# Balance chemical reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry

I want to balance reaction between glutamic acid and sodium carbonate. Can you check my answer whether it's true or false?? thank you.

C5H9NO4 + Na2CO3 = C5H7Na2NO4 + H2O + CO2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're wrong.
I suspect This reaction forms [Monosodium glutamate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monosodium_glutamate) (NaC5H7NO4) which would mean you would have to balance by reacting 2 HC5H8NO4 for each Na2CO3, and result in double the H2O and CO2. (Decomposed from H2CO3)

But aren't questions like this (without a real question) Not Allowed?

Comment: thank u so much for your answer. Sorry, I'm new to this site.

Comment: Questions like this are right on the border @adam, it's always better to explain your work as to how you came to the conclusion rather than just asking if it's correct.  Welcome :)